# Scheduler, CrudRepository and TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa, scheduler

I have a CrudRepository and a method to remove data:

```
public interface SampleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Sample, String> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("delete from Sample where creationTimestamp <= ?1")
    public void deleteOutdatedData(Instant expirationTimestamp);
}
```

It works if I use a rest controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delele", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteOldData(@RequestParam(value = "date") String date) {
        sampleRepository.deleteOutdatedData(Instant.parse(date));
}
```

I'd like to implement a scheduler to remove outdated data.
For example:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${clean-processing-delay}")
public void cleanOutdatedData() {
    Instant instant = Instant.now().minusMillis(expirationInterval);
    sampleRepository.deleteOutdatedData(instant);
}
```

The scheduler works at the right time, but I catch an exception:

> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing
>   an update/delete query;  nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3576#issuecomment-295983737)?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encase your method in a transaction, like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${clean-processing-delay}")
  @Transactional
  public void cleanOutdatedData() {
    Instant instant = Instant.now().minusMillis(expirationInterval);
    sampleRepository.deleteOutdatedData(instant);
  }
```